# How to prevent Firefox from hiding the 'http://' URL prefix?

Tags: firefox, url, prefix

I upgraded to Firefox 7.0.1 and the ['Google Shortener'](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-shortener/) stops working. I think this happens because in [Firefox 7.0.1](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/7.0.1/releasenotes/) the `http://` URL prefix is now hidden by default.

[image]

How do I get the `http://` back in the location bar? I checked in the `about:config` and could not find a entry for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this post](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/880180#answer-252525), you can revert it to the old behavior by setting *browser.urlbar.trimURLs* to false in **about:config**.

Comment: lsxex - thnx it works.