# How to prevent Firefox converting 'localhost/*' URLs into search queries?

Tags: firefox, search, localhost, url

Since upgrading from Firefox 3.6.x, my address bar has a quirk that never used to be there. When I type in, for example:

```
localhost/my_dir/index.php
```

Firefox turns it into a search query, my search engine is Google. To work around this (after forgetting I need to do this almost every time for FF), I must type in:

```
http://localhost/my_dir/index.php
```

This way, I am directed correctly to my localhost server. I don't need to do this for any other browser, and I thought [this Q/A on URL trimming](https://superuser.com/questions/341499/how-to-prevent-firefox-from-hiding-the-http-url-prefix) might change the behaviour, but it didn't.

Any ideas on how I can prevent 'localhost' from being turned into a search query?

Comment: This should not happen anymore as `browser.fixup.domainwhitelist.localhost` with `true` is introduced in recent versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Type `about:config` in the URL bar
2. In the filter search box, type `browser.fixup.alternate.suffix`
3. Double click this entry to edit it and remove: `.com`

Now your localhost files should work without having to add `http://`.

Comment: This doesnt work for me! I've restarted Firefox and entering "localhost:4567" does a google search!

Comment: I do not think this is the correct answer to **this** question, as it rather prevents FF appending `.com` to anything you type into the address bar. However, this works fine. For the sake of completeness: I found this setting better to use: `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled`, as above solution still prepended `.www` (there's a separete setting for this (called `browser.fixup.alternate.prefix)`.

Comment: @IanVaughan With regard to the question, I consider this to be the correct answer, since it actually is about search queries: http://superuser.com/questions/382905/how-to-prevent-firefox-converting-localhost-urls-into-search-queries#answer-506884

Comment: I'd love to understand what the Mozilla team was thinking here. It must be annoying to them and there web developers as well. At least it should include so cleverness on finding out "localhost" or with a period like "test.local" I mean, how hard can that be?

Answer (score 7):

1. In the Location bar, type about:config and press Enter.
2. The about:config "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear. Click I'll be   careful, I promise!, to continue to the about:config page.
3. In the Search field, type **keyword.enabled**.Double-click the keyword.enabled preference to set its value to false.

Please note that this will also prevent things that aren't URL-like from being used as search terms. For example, after making this change, if you type "how to tell if an egg is boiled" in the search bar, you'll just get a DNS error.

Other answers on this page give a way to attempt your suffix-less server name without modification (let's say you have a server in your domain called `git`, when you type just `git/` and there is a DNS problem, instead of navigating to `www.git.com` you'll just get a DNS error page).

[solution from Mozilla](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-web-address-bar#w_turning-off-the-internet-keyword-search)

Answer (score 7):

If you still want to be able to search from the address bar, but you also want to be able to open local URLs, you can set the `about:config` property `browser.fixup.dns_first_for_single_words` to `true`, which will do a DNS query for single words like `localhost` or `myserver` and only turn it into a search if the DNS query fails.

This gives you the best of both worlds - you can still search from the address bar, but if you put in the name of a machine on your LAN, then you'll just connect to that instead (assuming your DNS or `hosts` file is set up correctly of course!)

Comment: That helped me now. It should be the default but for some reason isn't. That's probably causing more trouble than it helps (not sure it's any good at all).

Comment: @ygoe I suppose it's aimed at corporate networks, where someone might try to search for "dhcp" or "exchange" to find out what they are, and instead of getting search results, the browser tries to connect to actual servers with those names and the user gets either an unexpected web page or a timeout due to a firewall block.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is kind of a weird solution, but you could map `localhost.com` to `127.0.0.1` with your `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

Start `notepad` as administrator (by using the context menu on-top of it in the Start menu) and open the file `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, then add an entry like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.com
```

to the end of the file. Save. Now you should be able to use localhost.com in place of localhost, which Firefox shouldn't complain about. Note that this works for practically any domain name you want, so you can make it shorter.

Comment: I've been using this method since I discovered it a couple of weeks ago. I use `local.host`. This is a much simpler solution than configuring the search engines in the browser. :)

Comment: Hmm... my hosts file already has "127.0.0.1       localhost" in it, I added the new entry, saved as admin - checked, restarted Firefox... same behaviour. @iglvzx: Do you literally type in "local.host/xyz" to the address bar after adding that to hosts?

Comment: @Danjah Yes, that's what I do. What did you add to your host file?

Comment: I added another line, under "127.0.0.1 localhost", "127.0.0.1       localhost.com", is that correct?

Comment: Ahhh, I see now, yeah, when I write "localhost.com/my_dir/index.php" it works "as expected". Very lame; its a few less characters to type, but still another thing to remember for another browser, until it changes again :P

Comment: This will work in all of your browsers, and additionally you can make it shorter (e.g. `l.h` should work even.)

Comment: @JohnChadwick That is correct. You can even shorten it to two characters. `l.` will work, too. :P

Answer (score 3):

After trying the solutions already posted the problem was still occurring in my environment. A Google search directed to https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/disable-firefox-redirecting-to-localhost-com/

This blog post suggested changing the `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` property to `false`. This did the trick for me.

Comment: This solved it for me as well. Thanks, @axiopisty!

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this problem, I configured Firefox to always show the `http://` protocol in URL bar.

In `about:config`, set `browser.urlbar.trimURLs` to `false` (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/881261).

Answer (score 3):

As said [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2014/11/27/fix-firefox-searching-for-local-hostnames-immediately/):

1. Type `about:config` in the URL bar,
2. Create boolean parameter
   `browser.fixup.domainwhitelist.domain_name`
   (replace `domain_name` with your local domain name, like `localhost`),
3. Set new parameter's value to `true`.

Comment: In recent versions of Firefox, the key `browser.fixup.domainwhitelist.localhost` is already there and set to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

In more recent versions of Firefox the `about:config` key `browser.fixup.domainsuffixwhitelist.<domain>` did the trick for me.

E.g. create the key `browser.fixup.domainsuffixwhitelist.mycustomdomain` and set it to true and any domain ending with `.mycustomdomain` will not end up as a search.

According to https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2020/05/26/these-weeks-in-firefox-issue-74/ and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1634650 it's available since Firefox 78.