# Firefox, localhost works intermittently?

Tags: firefox

I am having a weird issue with Firefox with localhost.

When I got to:

```
http://localhost/mysite/mypage.html
```

It brings up google search:

```
Your search - localhost/mysite/mypage.html - did not match any documents.
```

But other times...it brings up my page in Firefox.

It works consistently in Chrome (I always see my web page)

Is there a setting on Firefox I can change to prevent this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Firefox converting 'localhost/\*' URLs into search queries?](https://superuser.com/questions/382905/how-to-prevent-firefox-converting-localhost-urls-into-search-queries)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's most likely because you have a space somewhere, Firefox sends it to search instead of substituting %20. Firefox will only replace spaces when it recognises you typing an address. Firefox doesn't automatically recognise localhost as a domain the same way it recognises *.com (etc), apparently, so it assumes you want to search. Your basic options are:

- Don't have any spaces in your site URLs, underscores work
- Manually put %20 instead of spaces when typing the URL in
- Actually type the `http://` in, i.e. type `http://localhost/` instead of `localhost/`
- Disable address bar searching

To disable address bar searching, navigate to `about:config` and set `keyword.enabled` to `false`.