# How to get the flatpak versioni of Firefox to treat localhost as an address without a protocol prefix?

Tags: firefox, localhost, flatpak

When I enter `localhost:8888` in the address bar, the flatpak version of Firefox opens a dialog to choose an application to open the link. If I use `http://localhost:8888` the page opens normally. I don't want to type `http://` every time. Is there a way to restore the non-flatpak behavior of converting `localhost:8888` to `http://localhost:8888` or work around it just for `localhost`?

I believe what is happening is that `localhost:` is getting interpreted as a protocol named `localhost` instead of e.g. `http` or `https`. I have found that `127.0.0.1:8888` does work, but I would prefer `localhost` to work because `loc<Tab>` is usually enough to open what I want but even tab completion hits this protocol issue. `127<Tab>` does not give me good tab completions but maybe it would if I used it more so 127.0.0.1 got more weight in the suggested URLs.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/382905/how-to-prevent-firefox-converting-localhost-urls-into-search-queries) solution?

Comment: I tried some of the options there but they didn't help. Some options I did not try because they require giving up features of the address bar that I would like to keep.

Comment: You can edit your question.  I would do that since, I don't know what solutions you have tried, and by not knowing that information I can't perform research

Comment: I just noticed an important clue while checking which things do not work -- I only see this behavior when using the flatpak version of Firefox, not the OS packaged version.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a [known issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1618094). The problem is that there is no API for the flatpak of Firefox to query for a `localhost` protocol handler and fall back to treating the term as an address if there is none like it can outside of the flatpak sandbox. Firefox can only pass the potential protocol to a handler outside of the sandbox. This is my interpretation of the discussion in the linked Bugzilla ticket.

I believe one workaround might be to register a `localhost` protocol handler that calls `xdg-open` again on `http://localhost:<port+rest of URL>` but I have not had time to experiment with this.

I am posting this as an answer to highlight that this is a known issue without a good workaround but not marking it as accepted. If someone comes up with a good workaround, it would be welcomed.