# Firefox removes http:// and treats URLs with spaces as searches

Tags: firefox, search, url

I routinely visit pages like `http://trac.server/milestone/Milestone Name Here`. In Firefox (11.0 on Ubuntu, but this has happened for a while), the URL is displayed as `trac.server/milestone/Milestone Name Here` (without the protocol).

If I then click into the URL bar (either to edit the URL, or just to resubmit it), and press Enter, then the spaces are assumed to indicate that I'm searching, and I get a nice Google search page trying to look for *trac.server/milestone/Milestone Name Here*. For extra points, this search page gets saved in my history results.

If I manually add the `http://` at the front of the URL, then the search is submitted correctly. But I don't want to have to do that.

This is annoying and time-wasting. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to turn off the URL trimming (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/341499/how-to-prevent-firefox-from-hiding-the-http-url-prefix)): setting `browser.urlbar.trimURLs` to `false` in `about:config`.